# FactorDB works in terminalo but not in python file

Tags: python, module, python-import, factorization

I found an amazing library online called [FactorDB](https://pypi.org/project/factordb-pycli/) and is pretty straight forward to use.

After installing using `pip install factordb-pycli` I can type in a Linux terminal `factordb 16` and I will receive `2 2 2 2`.

I now try, following the instructions, to use the library in a python file:

```
from factordb.factordb import FactorDB

f = FactorDB(16)
print (f)
```

Unfortunately the terminal returns:

```
<factordb.factordb.FactorDB object at 0x7fc25a1c4c50>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the project's README. There you will find example code how to use the library interface.

https://github.com/ryosan-470/factordb-pycli

Comment: please have a look at the project's README and see that I have exactly copy/pasted those examples

Answer (score 1):

I had to [reach out](https://github.com/ryosan-470/factordb-pycli/issues/8#issuecomment-560951326) the maintainer of the module, the solution was:

```
from factordb.factordb import FactorDB

f = FactorDB(16)
f.connect()
result = f.get_factor_list()
print(result)
```